# Keep connection alive for streaming in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, video-streaming, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm making a small web application which is built on ASP.NET Core. My application is for streaming video from clients to clients through service.

I've followed this post :

http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/

I've implemented the application of tutorial successfully, but, that was for streaming Video from server to clients.

What I wanna do now is :

- Clients register to service for streaming. (using video or audio tag)
- Service receives client submitted data (submit through POSTMAN)
- Service broadcast the data to its every registered clients.

Here is what I've implemented:

**(Index.cshtml)**

```
<div>
    <video  width="480" 
            height="320" 
            controls="controls" 
            autoplay="autoplay">
        <source     src="/api/video/initiate"
                    type="video/mp4">
        </source>
    </video>
</div>
```

**StreamingService**

```
public class StreamingService: IStreamingService
{
    public IList<Stream> Connections {get;set;}

    public StreamingService()
    {
        Connections = new List<Stream>();
    }

    public byte[] AnalyzeStream(Stream stream)
    {
        long originalPosititon = 0;
        if (stream.CanSeek)
        {
            originalPosititon = stream.Position;
            stream.Position = 0;
        }

        try
        {
            var readBuffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesReader;

            while ((byteRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, totalBytesRead, readBuffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += byteRead;

                if (totalBytesRead == readBuffer.Length)
                {
                    var nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
                    if (nextByte != -1)
                    {
                        var temp = new byte[readBuffer * 2];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, temp, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                        Buffer.SetByte(temp, totalBytesRead, (byte)nextByte);
                        readBuffer = temp;
                        totalBytesRead++;
                    }
                }
            }

            var buffer = readBuffer;
            if (readBuffer.Length != totalBytesRead)
            {
                buffer = new byte[totalBytesRead];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, totalBytesRead);
            }

            return buffer;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream.CanSeek)
                stream.Position = originalPosititon;
        }
    }
}
```

**VideoController**

```
public class VideoController: Controller
{
    private readonly IStreamingService _streamingService;

    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public VideoController(IStreamingService streamingService, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _streamingService = streamingService;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpGet("initiate")]
    public IActionResult Initiate()
    {
        _streamingService.Connections.Add(Response.Body);
    }

    [HttpPost("broadcast")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Broadcast()
    {
        // Retrieve data submitted from POSTMAN.
        var data = _streamingService.AnalyzeStream(Request.Body);

        foreach (var stream in _streamingService.Connections)
        {
            try
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
                _streamingService.Connections.Remove(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I send data from POSTMAN through api/video/broadcast . For loop ran and I got an exception said the stream has been disposed.

My question is:

- **How can I keep the stream alive for streaming ?**

(Stream created in api/video/initiate is kept alive and when a client calls api/video/broadcast , all initiated stream will update its date without having disposed)

Thank you,

Comment: Hi @Redplane, did you find a solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to keep the stream in cache?

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/memory.html). The simplest way it to add the cache services to the dependency injection container and the request the concrete implementation of [IMemoryCache](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/Extensions/Caching/Memory/IMemoryCache/index.html) through constructor injection in your VideoController (as you've done with IStreamingService and IHostingEnvironment).

Just add the stream to the cache and use the cached stream the next time api/video/broadcast is hit.

Be aware though that if you are on a webfarm or hosted in the cloud it is recommended to use [Distributed Cache](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/distributed.html) like Redis Cache, or else your cache could disapear unexpected. I use [Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/) for instance which works great!

Comment: But stream is disposed when I access it. Can I keep the connection between client and server by using IMemoryCache ?

Comment: My bad, I should've asked you something first. How have to registered IStreamingService? which lifetime? Transient, Scope, or Singleton?

Comment: I use IStreamingService as an Singleton (services.AddSingeton<IStreamingService, StreamingService>())